# How can i show the items of listview listview in sqaure shape?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview, dynamic

In the selected part of image these list of images are static, but i want to change it with dynamically which is come from the database. is there any good method to do this ?

[image]

Comment: This view is not meant to be scrolled, i suppose. It does not represent a listview. It can be be made without it as well.

Comment: can you give me a hint of solution ? If i don't use listview then how can i make it dynamically update through DB? because these small images come from db?

Comment: Use gridview to show like that

Comment: I also need space between these images to show circle, as you can see in picture? can i do it with GridView ?

Comment: No, that is not a good way to do it in this case. Instead align these items in a view a group of four relative layouts having linear layouts inside them. The two linearlayouts will be horizontal and the other will be vertical with every item containing same weight.

Comment: Yes, you are right . i do it same make as you told me . but the main problem is that list of items are come from database, and i have to set these items **statically** i want to make these items **dynamically**. @cafebabe1991

Comment: Position of the images will be static?  You want to change the images as per your database?

Comment: yes @Pawanpreet

Comment: you are getting images url from the database?

Comment: no. these are Bitmap Images in form of byte[] array

Comment: you can set single image from byte[] to a imageview???

Comment: yes @Pawanpreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: code result]

you can get image from the database and set to each of this imageview.